# How to redirect using Perl?

Tags: perl, redirect, cgi

I am new to Perl and I am trying to redirect a user to another page on my server when he enters the right password. The page that I want to redirect to (hello.pl) is in the same directory as my Perl script for the page; however when I try to redirect all I get is a message:

```
Status: 302 Found Location: hello.pl
```

But the browser doesn't actually go to the hell0.pl which is what I want. I looked online and in the Perl books but it looks that I'm doing everything right, can someone tell me why my code isn't redirecting?  Here's the code for it:
I omitted the code for setting up page and getting user input stored in $var ie I did $var = CGI->new at the top of the file, also I am using CGI.pm as a library.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wT
use strict;

use CGI qw(:standard);

print header,
      start_html("Input Form"),
      start_form,
      "Please enter your username:",
      textfield(-name=>'username',
                      -maxlength=>20),p,
      "Please enter your password:",
      password_field(-name=>'password',
                      -maxlength=>20),p,
      submit,
      end_form,
      hr, "\n";

my $var = CGI->new;
my $username  = $var->param("username");
my $password  = $var->param("password");

my $open = "opensesamie";

  if ($password ne $open) {
          print "Sorry wrong password";
  } else {
          print $var->redirect('hello.pl');
          print $var->start_html,p,
          "Hello, $username",p,
          "The current time is ",scalar(localtime),
          $var->end_html;
  }

print end_html;
```

Comment: @Borodin I'm not trying to imply that you don't know what these variables are, it's just what I chose to call them. I don't know if you have seen my comments above about including headers but I made an edit to make it clear, and if I use the code you originally posted, then I still get no redirect.

Comment: My answer was wrong and I deleted it a while ago. I apologise. There is no need to put those `use` statements anywhere after the top of the program. Nor is there any need for the `header` call or the `start_html`/`end_html` calls, and there should be only one `redirect`. How are you running your CGI program? If you just run it from the command line then that is all you should expect to see. You need to execute it by loading the CGI script from a wrb browser. It is the Web browser that sees the 302 status and then loads the `Location` address.

Comment: You misunderstand. You should *never* call *anything* `var` as it doesn't describe the purpose of the variable.

Comment: Okay i'll erase the edit then, I got your point about the var, thanks, I'll keep it in mind next time I write code.

Comment: How are you running your program? Where are you seeing the output you describe?

Comment: @Borodin I am running my program in the browser. I see the username and password fields when I enter user name, followed by password and click submit I get to the logic portion that I posted, but if I put in the right password instead of redirect the text is printed to the browser window .

Comment: I think you have some `print` statements before the `if` that you show, making the headers from the `redirect` call appear within an HTML block. Please may we see your entire code?

Comment: @Borodin sorry for the delay had hard time formatting the code, but it is posted now.

Comment: It confirms my guess and validates my answer.

Comment: Why do you output HTML when you redirect? It won't be seen.

Comment: @ikegami sorry, what am I supposed to erase? Yes, HTML is useless here.

Comment: @Stochastic13: I'm sorry if you didn't like my edit of your question. It is a big help to others if you add a hyperlink to the documentation for any modules you're using. I thought you had made a mistake when you removed it so I rolled it back, but now it is gone again.

Comment: @Stochastic13: Do you understand the problem and solution now?

Comment: @Borodin I didn't remove anything you edited, must have been someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the delay - I have had to set up a working HTTP server to test my code.

Thank you for posting your full code. It is as I guessed - you have started a message at the top of your program and then added the `redirect` output to it, whereas you need *only* the redirect output sent to the client.

I think this is what you need. It checks to see if both the `username` and `password` parameters have been sent. If not then the form must be displayed to ask for them. If so then either an error message must be sent if the password is wrong, or a redirect if it is right.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI qw(:standard);

my %names = map { $_ => 1 } param;
my $open  = 'opensesamie';

if ($names{username} and $names{password}) {

   my $username = param('username');
   my $password = param('password');

   if ($password eq $open) {
      print
         header,
         start_html,
         p('Sorry, wrong password'),
         end_html;
   }
   else {
      print redirect('hello.pl');
   }
}
else {

   print
      header,
      start_html('Input Form'),
      start_form,
         p('Please enter your username:'),
         textfield( -name => 'username', -maxlength => 20),
         p('Please enter your password:'),
         password_field( -name => 'password', -maxlength => 20),
         p,
         submit,
      end_form,
      hr,
      end_html;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to set up the server and write this code, could you explain to me what the line: my %names = map { $_ => 1 } param;  does?

Comment: @Stochastic13: `param` returns a list of names of the parameters passed to the CGI program. The `map` call creates a hash that uses those names as keys and 1 for every value. It makes it really simple to check whether a given parameter has been passed, by writing `if ($names{param_name}) { ... }`. In this case I use it to check whether the username and password parameters have both been passed by writing `if ($names{username} and $names{password}) { ... }`

Comment: The advantage of my earlier answer over this one is it gives you a chance to reenter the password if you entered the wrong password

Answer (score 1):

You are outputting two headers. Don't use both `header` and `redirect` for the same request.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wT
use strict;

use CGI qw(:standard);

my $cgi = CGI->new;
my $username  = $cgi->param("username");
my $password  = $cgi->param("password");

if ($password eq "opensesamie") {
   print $cgi->redirect('hello.pl');
   exit();
}

print header;
print start_html("Please Login");
print p({-class => "error"}, "Incorrect password") if $password;
print ... print the form here ...;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand, where am I calling a header followed by redirect on the same object? After I call set $var = CGI->new I only call a header if the password is wrong otherwise I calls redirect.

Comment: Re "I only call a header if the password is wrong otherwise I calls redirect.", That's what you *should* do (as I said and showed in my answer), but you *actually* call `print header` unconditionally.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but the reason I chose Bodin's answer is because he spent a lot of time setting up the server and trying to help me, but I agree your code is supperior.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have something like this.

Have you started the HTTP `print` statements somewhere before the `if` that tests the password? That would make the headers that `print $cgi->redirect` just part of the HTML text.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI;

my %passwords;

my $cgi = CGI->new;

my $username = $cgi->param('username');
my $password = $cgi->param('password');

print
   $cgi->header,
   $cgi->start_html;

if ($password ne $open) {
   print 'Sorry wrong password';
}
else {
   print $var->redirect('hello.pl');
   print
      $var->start_html, p,
      "Hello, $username", p,
      "The current time is ", scalar(localtime),
      $var->end_html;
}
```

You need to separate the success/failure completely, like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI;

my %passwords;

my $cgi = CGI->new;

my $username = $cgi->param('username);
my $password = $cgi->param('password);

my $open = $passwords{$username};

if ($password ne $open) {
   print
      $cgi->header,
      $cgi->start_html;
      $cgi->p('Sorry wrong password'),
      $cgi->end_html;
}
else {
   print $var->redirect('hello.pl');
}
```

Comment: I made the changes you suggested in my code and still no redirect but it just prints: Status: 302 Found Location: hello.pl